# Binding a JSON to a Table

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

EDIT: I updated my function!
I want to bind the JSON data to my sap.ui.table but I kinda have no clue how this works

So this is my table:

```
<content>
<t:Table id="transactionUiTable" 
                columnHeaderVisible="true" 
                selectionMode="Single" 
                selectionBehavior="RowSelector"
                enableColumnReordering="false" 
                enableGrouping="false" 
                showColumnVisibilityMenu="false" 
                enableSelectAll="false" 
                enableCustomFilter="false"
                enableBusyIndicator="false" 
                rows="{path: '/'}" 
                rowSelectionChange="onTableSelectionChange">
                    <t:toolbar>
                        <Toolbar id="toolbar">
                                <Input width="15%" id="transactionId"  value="txn_18KlBw2eZvKYlo2CdHGDlpAJ"/>
                                <Button text="Search Transaction" type="Emphasized" icon="sap-icon://search" press="onTransactionByTransactionId"/> 
                                <Button text="Transactionlist" type="Unstyled" press="onTransactionList"/>
                                <Button text="Customer Transactionlist" type="Unstyled" press="onCustomerTransactionList"/>
                                <ToolbarSpacer/>
                                <Button icon="sap-icon://action-settings" type="Default" />
                        </Toolbar>
                    </t:toolbar>
                    <t:columns>
                        <t:Column id="id" hAlign="Center" width="10%">
                            <Label id="labelId" text="Transaction Id"></Label>
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{orderId}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnDate" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelDate" text="Date"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnAmount" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelAmount" text="Amount"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnCurrency" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelCurrency" text="Currency"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnFee" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelFee" text="Fee"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnNet" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelNet" text="Net"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column id="columnType" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelType" text="Type"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                            <t:Column id="columnStatus" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label id="labelStatus" text="Status"></Label>
                        </t:Column>
                    </t:columns>
                </t:Table>
            </content>
```

By clicking on the Button with the text "Search Transaction", I want to call via GET to a service with a transactionId, which can be wrote into a Input field, I already filled it with the value "txn_blablabla"

so this is my function:

```
onTransactionByTransactionId : function() {
        this.oView = this.getView();
        var query =  this.oView.byId("transactionId").getValue();

        var oJsonModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oJsonModel.loadData("/retrieveTransacion?transactionId=" + query , {}, false);

        var oData = oJsonModel.getProperty("/");
        this.oView.setModel(oData);


    }
```

so on my variable oData I got my JSON binded, but how can I bind those JSON data on my table columns?

for example I want to bind the JSON data amount with the column with the id "columnAmount" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually almost there. The only thing you need to do is to set the model to the JSONModel rather than to the raw JSON data, i.e.:

`this.oView.setModel(oData);` -> `this.oView.setModel(oJsonModel);`

You may also want to move initialisation of your `JSONModel` and the binding to the view to the `init` section, as this doesn't need to happen every time the search button is pressed. Moving it to the init-method would get your code to perform faster and I think it would make it more understandable as well.

Please find a slightly cleaned and modified version (so that it can connect to the public countrylist service) in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/laqefak/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks mate that really helped me with my problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: 1 more question in your case you get an JSON data with this format back: [ {JSON DATA} ] , while in my case I get this JSON Data back: {JSON DATA} it seems like those brackets missing at my JSON Data causes me some problems because the binding isn't working, do I need to convert that JSON data to an array first or what is my problem?

Comment: The [] brackets means that you're dealing with an array. {} is an object and can be part of an array. If you bind an aggregation, such as the rows (items) of a table, you'll have to bind them to an array. Could it be that the array you're wanting to bind is part of that {} object, e.g. {Products: [ {id:product1} , {id: product2}]}? In that case you'll need to bind to /Products instead of /.

Comment: Thanks so far for your big interest in helping me, when this works you just made my day ! I got this JSON data: {  
   "id":"18KlBw2eZvKYlo2CdHGDlpAJ",
   "amount":112233,
   "availableOn":1466121600,
   "created":1465548036,
   "currency":"usd",
   "description":null,
   "fee":3285,
   "feeDetails":[ .... ],
   "net":108948,
   "source":"ch_18KlBw2eZvKYlo2Cyl4tdavk",
   "sourcedTransfers":{ .... },
   "status":"pending",
   "type":"charge"}
so I cut some things out of it since I dont need those feeDetails, but I want to bind id,amount,created,currency,fee,net,status and type

Comment: so I need to bind rows to more paths than one? or how is that done like this way:  `rows="{path: '/id', '/amount', '/created' }"`   and so on ? and the `<t:template><Text text="{amount}"/></t:template>` stay the same?

Comment: It seems that your service just returns one object (not an array). Why would you want to bind that to a table? A table is meant to display multiple lines and doesn't like it when you bind it to a single object.

Comment: Because I want to display those information in table format to the user (or in other words, I'm working as a working student and my boss wants that to display for the user in a table format)

Comment: Maybe you should ask your boss to talk to a UX consultant. But that's besides the point. If you have a singleton, you can't bind it to a table. What you'll need to to is to read the response of the service and wrap that in an array. I.e.: `var aResponse = [ oResponse ]`. Then you can push that data into a JSONModel: `var oJSonModel = new JSONModel(aResponse)`, and bind that to your view: `this.oView.setModel(oJSonModel)`.